# Thinkpad X13 and Linux Mint 20

Tags: linux-mint, thinkpad

I realized some issues with external devices on my new Laptop (Thinkpad X13, Intel Core i5-10210U). The issues include:

- Hibernate does not work with external monitor connected.
- Ethernet over Thunderbold dock occasionally looses connection, leading to whole system to freeze. Also, `ifconfig` hangs in this case and never finishes listing available interfaces.
- HDMI display over Thunderbolt is sometimes not detected.
- Also, Cinnamon Settings seem to not work properly, as I found following output on `dmesg`: `cinnamon-settin[3194]: segfault at ... error 5 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.6400.3`

Are their any reported issues on the 10th generation i5 processors, or any ideas where the issues could come from. I thought that Thinkpads are supposed to have great Unix compatibility, but now I start worrying.

Comment: Hardware compatibility has improved by leaps and bounds, but "supposed to have great Unix compatibility" is a very generic statement. The issue appears to be with a specific piece of your hardware, nothing to do with the CPU core. Go check the Mint compatibility list: "https://community.linuxmint.com/hardware/" as a start. Your thunderbolt dock may have limited driver support, or missing tweaks.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. My understanding is that Display- and Thunderbolt-hardware is included in the CPU, that's why I assumed general issues with 10th gen Intel CPU's. The HDMI sleep issue also appears when having the display connected to the laptops HDMI interface, not the dock. This would have been my hotfix until everything works as expected.

Do you have any tips on how to find more concrete information about the issues on my machine? `dmesg` does not say a lot...